# How assigned access to user on a folder (alfresco .net)

Tags: .net, permissions, directory, alfresco

I'm searching a way for add a list of user who can access to a folder on Alfresco, using C#, I can't do it with dotcmis; et not found a URL which do this with Rest API.

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to add permissions to the folder or get the current permissions for the folder?

Comment: I want to give user, permission to access to folder, for exemple
user1 can write and reas on folder 1
user2 can't write on folder 1 but he can read contenent of folder 1
sorry for my english i'm francophone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From C# you should use the Alfresco REST-API. To set permissions just set the Permission Group for the user or group on the node.
Best way to dig into the REST-API is to use the API-Explorer. See the permissions example in the [node update](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/updateNode) example in the swagger documentation.